# Issue pulling a docker container from an organization into kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

Where I work we have docker premium accounts and I have setup a basic failover site for one of our servers `docker.io/organization/failover:latest`. I am attempting to pull this into a kubernetes cluster, 1.28, however when I use the repository address I get a permission denied error when it is private (using secrets in the same namespace), and a message that it does not exist when I make it public.

I am using the same address for my github workflow to build the container and that works fine. If I move it into my personal repo and use the docker.io/user/failover:latest it works perfectly fine public or private. Is there a special path you need to use to pull frm organizational repositories?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: failover
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: failover
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: failover
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/organization/failover:latest
        name: failover
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

The error I get, when it is set as a public repo is

```
Failed to pull image "docker.io/organization/repo": reading manifest latest in docker.io/organization/repo: manifest unknown
```

UPDATE:
Figuired out part of this, the latest tag is not dynamic. Still cannot get the login part to work however with the kubernetes secret when private.
UPDATE #2
Figured out the permissions issue. The credentials were not nested properly under spec. Sorry to waste time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was 2 fold and not obvious from the manifest I posted.

1. the credentials were not nested properly
2. I was not pushing with the tag latest